# Writing a word backwards using only 1 string converted to an array, a character, and an integer

Tags: java, arrays, string, integer

I'm trying to create a code that writes an array backwards and can only use an array, character, and an integer. So far I have this, but it isn't doing anything. I'm a beginner at `java`.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class TestingArraysUsingOneArray
{
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
      {
      String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter any text that you want to reverse.");
      char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
      char current;
      int a = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i>=str.length()%2; i++) {
         current = str.charAt(a);
         charArray[a] = str.charAt(str.length()-a);
         charArray[str.length()-a] = current;
         a++;
      }
      System.out.println(charArray);
      }
   }
}
```

The output I'm getting is `hello` when I enter in `hello`. What do I need to change to get this program to work?

Comment: you need to better explain your homework assignment.

Comment: I swear this isn't a homework assignment, it is a project that my dad gave me as a challenge. Plus, I'm on winter break anyway.

Comment: lets redefine homework as something you aren't being paid to do in the professional world.  Also, you need to give us way more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your don't need half the code. I would try to make it as simple as possible.  Try this

```
String str = ...
for(int i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0;  i--)
    System.out.print(str.chatAt(i));
System.out.println();
```

If the assignment says you have to reverse an array of chars you can do this.

```
String str = ...

char[] chars = str.toCharArray();
for(int i = 0; i < chars.length/2; i++) {
    char ch = chars[i];
    chars[i] = chars[chars.length - i - 1];
    chars[chars.length - i - 1] = ch;
}
System.out.println(new String(chars));
```

As you can see this is needlessly complicated, so you would not do this.  Another way you can do this if you don't want to use a loop is

```
String str = ...

System.out.println(new StringBuilder(str).reverse());
```

Comment: That's what I did for a start, but my dad said there was a way to do by replacing characters in an array.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one thing, I think you want `i<str.length()/2` - this will give you half the length. If you say `i>=str.length()%2`, you're getting the remainder when its length is divided by 2 - which is always either 1 or 0, and the loop continues as long as i is more than either 1 or 0. This should result in an infinite loop. Also, you don't need the variable a, as it is always equivalent to i. This, however, results in the string index being out of bounds sometimes, but I'll let you figure out how to solve that.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is replace the first character with the last and so on..

```
    char[] charArray = str.toCharArray();
    char current;

    for (int i = 0; i < charArray.length / 2; i++) {
     current = charArray[i];
     charArray[i] = charArray[charArray.length - i - 1];
     charArray[charArray.length - i - 1] = current;
    }
```

The `a` int is completely redundant, and it would be a second int in your code - don't forget the variable in the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is never entering because it should be `i < str.length()`, because at the moment when `i` is 0, the current check will immediately fail.

With that condition set, you need to change the two instances of `str.length()-a` to `str.length()-a-1`, because `str.length-a` when `a` is 0 will cause an StringIndexOutOfBoundException because the maximum index you can access is `str.length-1`.

Those are just corrections to the existing code. There's a better, more concise way of reversing the string suggested in another answer, which is the one you should accept.